# Prestashop Smarty email regular expression validation

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, smarty, prestashop

I have a form, and when I submit it, I want to make an email validation before. I created a js file, put in theme's js directory, included it on the page and my page is WHITE. I activated the errors and I saw that this is the error:

> SmartyCompilerException: Syntax Error in template
>   "D:\Projects\mpm_shop\themes\pmart\js\processContactFormEmail.js"
>   on line 44 "var re =
>   /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-+])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;"
>   - Unexpected ",", expected one of: "}" , " " , ATTR in
>   D:\Projects\mpm_shop\tools\smarty\sysplugins\smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php on line 667

My regex is this one:

> var re =
>   /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-+])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;

and I try to match it like this:

```
if (!email.match(re)) {
                    $('#email').css('border', '1px solid red'); 
                    $('.errorEmail').html('Email non è valido');
                    valid = false;
                }
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in your regex :

```
var re = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-+])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
```

In the first group, there is a dash between . and + (`.-+`), which is the cause for the error.

You simply need to escape it :

```
var re = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.\-+])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
```

Next time you have regex issues, you can use an online regexp tool, like [Regexr](http://www.regexr.com/), which is very helpful to test and validate your expression !

Comment: Hi, thx for answering! Actually, the solution to my problem is to use starting and ending smarty tags like described in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158012/use-regex-within-a-smarty-template.
I put that, but your regex is returning me this "SyntaxError: invalid range in character class"

Comment: @irimieandrei, I tested again, and it works for me. Here's a test fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/p7FFD/1/

Comment: I put var re = '{literal}'+ /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.\-+])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/ +'{/literal}';
in my js file, and no error is outputed now, but for "test@yahoo.com" it says that email is not valid. In your example I see that is working, don't know why is not working in mine :(

Comment: Use `{literal} var re = .... {/literal}`, do not concatenate `{literal}` to your regex. This expression is used in Smarty to ignore content inside it.

Comment: I moved validation directly in PHP, anyway thanks for the answers guys !